# Roll-on epoxy over self leveling concrete

Tags: basement, self-leveling-concrete, epoxy

Just started cleaning up my basement and trying to make some livable space for cheap.

Right now we just have the concrete floor from the foundation, It is not level and it is very rocky ( Not smooth at all).

I plan to pour self leveler until the floor is smooth and level, then I will roll on the epoxy.

Will the epoxy provide sufficient protection for the self leveling concrete?

Comment: Off topic: Be aware that "livable space" requires legal egress windows for fire safety.

Comment: A better question would be "is epoxy paint appropriate over self-leveler?" You'll need to check with the manufacturer on that one. Also be aware that those products have a maximum thickness that may not accommodate your needs. You might look into a poured gypsum floor.

Comment: I have used both 2 part and single can epoxies on self leveling compounds. Read the instructions it may take several weeks cure time prior to putting the epoxy on. I have better results with 2 part but some are not intended for use in a living space (voc's in those take 3 days to cure and require active ventilation). The epoxy did provide a better surface and sealed the floors quite well.

Comment: ObDisclaimer: **Never spray epoxy** or any 2-part paint wothout a moon suit, supplied air etc.  Brush/roll is fine, the toxin is in the resin not the thinner.  If the SLC is fully cured, overcoating it should be fine.  If it's not, wait.

Answer (score 1):

I saw on another thread that someone said to use a concrete resurfacer. Which means it isn't self levelling. So the work to get it flat will be about 3000 more calories than your self levelling idea. But from what i know about floors you have to wait 20 days after pouring concrete before putting the epoxy down. Because of moisture evaporation and the drying process. Good luck.